# crear un typedef de struct y usar funciones para pedir datos

Tags: c

El error me dice:

> could not convert ´(Persona)(&p) from 'Persona*' to 'Persona'

```
struct Persona{
    char nombre[20];
    int edad;
};typedef struct Persona arreglo [5];

Persona cargarArreglo(Persona);
void Imprimir(Persona);

int main()
{
    arreglo p;
    cargarArreglo(p);
    Imprimir(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: Es muy probable que estes usando C++ en lugar de C. De otro modo el primer mensaje del compilador debería ser que no encuentra "Persona". Bajo el modelo que tienes actualmente, la forma correcta de referirse al tipo es "struct Persona"

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que al crear el typedef de esa forma le estas diciendo al compilador que cualquier variable declarada como **arreglo** sera una arreglo de 5 posiciones y tus funciones **cargarArreglo** e **Imprimir** reciben un tipo de dato **Persona** y le estas pasando un arreglo de 5 posiciones de Persona

si quieres hacerlo de esa forma deber de llamarlo de la siguente manera

`cargarArreglo(*p);` o `cargarArreglo(&p[i]);`
`Imprimir(*p);` o `Imprimir(&p[i]);`

Te recomiendo esto:

```
typedef struct Persona
{
    char nombre[20];
    int edad;
}Persona;

void cargarArreglo(Persona ** n, int cantidad)
{
    (*n) = (Persona*)malloc(sizeof(Persona) * cantidad);
    memset((*n), 0, sizeof(Persona) * cantidad);

    for(int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++)
    {
        char num = 48 + i;
        strcpy((*n)[i].nombre, "Nombre ");
        strcat((*n)[i].nombre, &num);
        (*n)[i].edad = 20 + i;
    }

void Imprimir(Persona n){
     printf("Nombre = %s, edad = %d", n.nombre, n.edad);
}
int main()
{
    Persona * p;
    int cant = 5;
    cargarArreglo(&p, cant);

    for(int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
        Imprimir(p[i]);

    return 0;
}
```